# Create list of row names based on search criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
     A            B     C        D      E            F            G        H
1                 Q1     Q2      Q3     Q4   Search criteria:     60     Asset 2
2   Asset 1       15     85      90     70                               Asset 3
3   Asset 2       40     80      45     60                               Asset 3
4   Asset 3       30     60      55     60                               Asset 5                       
5   Asset 4       12     72      25     15
6   Asset 5       60     48      27     98
7
```

In `Cells A1:E6` I have different assets with their performance from quarter `Q1-Q4`. 
In `Column H` I want to have a list of all assets that match the search criteria in `Cell G1`. 
In this case the search criteria is `60` which can be found in the `Cells A1:E6` for the `Assets 2`, `3` and `5`.

As you can see it can happen that the search criteria exists mutliple times in a row (like in `Row 4`). Therefore, I want that the asset is listed two times in the list (like `Asset 3`).

Do you have any idea of a formula that could create this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in H1

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$2:$E$6)/($B$2:$E$6=$G$1),ROW(1:1)))
```

and copy down.

[image]

---

If you are using an older version of Excel this can be done with an array version of SMALL:

```
=INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF($B$2:$E$6=$G$1,ROW($B$2:$E$6)),ROW(1:1)))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your answer. Is there also a solution for this issue without the AGGREGATE function becasue I am using MS Excel 2007.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the additional help.

Comment: Hi Scott, is there any trick to modify the formula in case the array is not in Cells A1:E6. For example I put the array into cells C5:G10. Therefore, I also changed your formula to: =INDEX($C$5:$C$10,SMALL(IF($D$5:$G$10=$I$5,ROW($D$5:$G$10)),ROW($C5:$G5))) but now I only get #NUM! error?

Comment: First the `$C$5:$C$10` should be just `C:C` next the second `ROW($C5:$G5)` should start at `ROW(1:1)`  see my formulas above.  This is a counter not really a range reference and it needs to start at 1 and be relative so it increases as it is copied down.