# Make formula for list of row names independent from entire column and first row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
     A            B     C        D      E            F            G        H
1                 Q1     Q2      Q3     Q4   Search criteria:     60     Asset 2
2   Asset 1       15     85      90     70                               Asset 3
3   Asset 2       40     80      45     60                               Asset 3
4   Asset 3       30     60      55     60                               Asset 5                       
5   Asset 4       12     72      25     15
6   Asset 5       60     48      27     98
7
```

In `Cells A1:E6` I have different assets with their performance from quarter Q1-Q4. 
In `Column H` I list all assets that match the search criteria in `Cell G1`.
In this case the search criteria is `60` which can be found in the `Cells A1:E6` for the `Assets 2`, `3` and `5`.

For creating the list I use the formula from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52501008/create-list-of-row-names-based-on-search-criteria):

```
=INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF($B$2:$E$6=$G$1,ROW($B$2:$E$6)),ROW(1:1)))
```

All this works fine so far.

---

Now when I move the `Cells A1:E6` in the sheet for example to `D9:H14` the array formula keeps only working if it still refers to `A:A` and `ROW(1:1)` which might be a problem if the user decides to delete `ROW(1:1)`. Therefore, I tried to modify the formula to:

```
=INDEX($D$9:$D$14,SMALL(IF($E$10:$H$14=$J$10,ROW($E$10:$H$14)),ROW($D$9:$H$9)))
```

However, with this modification I get `#NUM!` error.

Do you have any idea if it is possible to make the array formula independent from `A:A` and `ROW(1:1)` so it refers only to the `Cells A1:E6` and automatically moves when the those cells are moved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use excel 2013 or later then you can use following formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$10:$D$14,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$5)/($E$10:$H$14=$J$10),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can limit `A:A` to `A1:A6` so that it would adjust as necessary when you move it. Your formula should thus be now

```
=INDEX(A1:A6,SMALL(IF($B$2:$E$6=$G$1,ROW($B$2:$E$6)),ROW(1:1)))
```

As for `ROW(1:1)`, your top formula should always be `ROW(1:1)` and when you drag it down, then next formula should have `ROW(2:2)`. When you move your top formula somewhere else and the `ROW(1:1)` changes to something like `ROW(9:9)` or anything, change it to `ROW(1:1)`.

Please note that 'moving' your formula is different from 'dragging it down'.

**EDIT:**

So after you moved your data set, the top formula should now be:

```
=INDEX($D$9:$D$14,SMALL(IF($E$10:$H$14=$J$10,ROW($E$10:$H$14)),ROW(1:1)))
```

This is assuming that cell `G1` (criteria) is also moved to `J10`.